# Are human-looking Jedi/Sith like Palpatine and the Skywalkers the same (human) species as non-Force users?

Tags: star-wars

Is there a canon mention that Kenobi, Windu, Palpatine, the Skywalkers etc. are the same human species as all the other humans in [the Skyriver Galaxy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35637/whats-the-name-of-the-galaxy-far-far-away/35642#35642) like Han Solo?

They look like humans, but we know that they're different in at least one characteristic: midi-chlorian hosting, which I suppose humans can't do *as per definition*.

---

Answers only from Canon, please. EU is welcome...

Comment: Just to clarify: by "Homo Sapiens" and "humans" you mean humans from Star Wars galaxy, correct? (e.g. those living on Coruscant/Corellia/Tattooine/etc....)

Comment: Since you never responded to my comment yet accepted my answer (which assumes that you're asking about "humans from Star Wars Galaxy", i edited the question accordingly, to distinguish it from related but different https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110205/are-the-humans-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-really-humans (asking about specifically whether Han Solo model humans are Homo Sapient)

Comment: The answer from @DVK-on-Ahch-To seems spot on, but I feel it worth mentioning that Mace Windu (one of the mentioned "Human" jedi in your example) is of a near-human species called Korun. Ill expand on it if I can find the canon quote I'm thinking of.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren - I always assumed Windu was a special species of "Kick-a** m****ers". (but yes, it's an interesting question of whether Korun are fully human or humanoid. I think that Korun can interbreed with normal humans so I'd classify them as same species)

Comment: Given that Star Wars takes place "a long, long time ago" in a "galaxy far, far away" they can't be human.

Comment: @jim - And indeed we know that they aren't; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/165774/20774

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Midi-chlorians are in microorganisms in **symbiotic relationship** with a living being that hosts them (think Mitochondria; or Chlorophyll in Earth plants; or Kanga Virus mutation in Thuselahs of David Weber's "Apocalypse Troll").

   Given that the Force tends to run strong in the families, it's clear that Midi-chlorian affinity/density is heritable; at least somewhat genetic in nature.

   However, having a specific genetic trait **in no way makes someone a different species**.

   So, merely being a Force-Sensitive (e.g. having high Midi-chlorian count) does no by itself mean Jedi aren't "human". So, we need to discuss how species is determined in general:
2. To decide whether the "human" Jedi are the same species as Homo Sapient, we must first look at how "Species" is defined. To misquote from my [answer about Superman's species](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45247/976):

   The definition of "species" is a bit murky (see ["Species Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_problem) Wikipedia entry in detail).

   Let's start with Wikipedia definition of "species (emphasis and ellipses mine - DVK):

   > In biology, a species is one of the basic units of **biological classification** and a **taxonomic rank**. A species is **often** defined as a group of organisms **capable of interbreeding and producing fertile offspring** (Note: often, not always. Discussed below).
   >
   > While in many cases this definition is adequate, the difficulty of defining species is known as the species problem. **Differing measures are often used, such as similarity of DNA, morphology, or ecological niche**.

   ---

   In light of those definitions:

   - Human Jedi clearly can interbreed with human non-Jedi (e.g. Corran Horn's mother was a Muggle, so was Queen Amidala). This makes Human Jedi the same species.
   - Leaving aside Midi-Chlorian affinity, there is no evidence that Jedi are genetically different from Humans (as a matter of fact, there's canon support for genetic identicalness - they use Midi-Chlorian counters to detect Jedi, whereas they could have used simple genetic tests if that was not the case).
   - Morphologically, "Human" Jedi are always described 100% human. Both G- and C- canon always stress that 100% of Jedi abilities come from the Force - without the Force they are 100% morphology.
   - Ecologically, they live in pretty much the same environment as other humans biologically (despite being adapted to wider range of hostile environment, e.g. vacuum, cold or hotness); and fulfill general "LEO/PeaceKeeper" ecological niche as other humans.

   **Based on all 3 definitions, "Human" Jedi are same species as other "Humans" in TGFFA.**

Comment: Did you say Muggle? Hm, must be something I overlooked. I'll have to read the books again.

Answer (score 6):

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, C-3PO says that Luke is "quite clever, you know... for a human being." So at the very least, C-3PO, a protocol droid who would presumably be aware of distinctions between species for diplomatic purposes, considers Luke, a Force-sensitive individual, to be human. (This is in addition to any number of official reference materials that list the species of all human-looking Jedi to be human.)

Answer (score 4):

Of course they are [human](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Human). They don't "host" [midi-chlorians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian), the midi-chlorians are microscopic organisms that live inside all living things, but are highly attracted to Force-sensitives; the more Force-sensitive a being is, the more midi-chlorians they will attract. George Lucas even stated, way back in 1977; "It is said that certain creatures are born with a higher awareness of the Force than humans. Their brains are different; they have more midi-chlorians in their cells." George Lucas explicitly stated 37 years ago that humans have midi-chlorians in their cells. I don't know what more evidence you could need, but [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi) is a link to Obi-Wan Kenobi's *Wookieepedia* page, where he is described as a human.

Comment: Presence of midi-chlorian defines a force-sensitive, not they are attracted to force-sensitive..

Comment: That is a debatable point. The article itself isn't entirely clear on the exact relationship between midi-chlorians and the Force.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what its canon-level is, but according to "*Star Wars: The Essential Guide to Alien Species*", humans are the galaxy's most common sentient species - of which there are thousands of variations & sub-species found throughout Republic/Imperial space. Although it never specifically calls them "Homo Sapiens", it does mention that the human race is believed to have originated on Coruscant, which would therefore make all other human races a subset of that original race.

So, if the intent of your question is "Are they all human, same as us?", then the answer is yes.

If your question means exactly what it says - "Are they Homo sapiens?", as opposed to Homo Starwarsicus or something, then I guess the answer would be No... they're a different kind of human.

Keep in mind, within the context of the lore, everything in Star Wars happened a "long, long time ago in a galaxy far, far away." Within that context, Earth is just one more human 'colony' that hasn't yet discovered (or re-discovered) space travel, and is basically ignorant of the rest of the universe.

Answer (score -1):

They can't be *homo sapiens* because they are reproductively isolated from all known examples of *homo sapiens* -- that's the definition of a separate species, regardless of whether or not they have similar DNA.

I see I need to clarify here. It's not that Jedi and Sith specifically aren't *homo sapiens*. There are no *homo sapiens* characters at all in *Star Wars*, because they have no contact with Earth and the *homo sapiens* species. The characters who look like *homo sapiens* may have identical DNA to *homo sapiens*, but they're still a different species, because of the reproductive isolation.

Comment: I don't know where you're getting this from. By that metric, the Pope isn't human.

Comment: The Pope is not reproductively isolated from humanity by the biiological definition. He doesn't reproduce at all, as far as we know, but if he did it would be with a _homo sapiens_, so he's human.

Comment: Last time I looked, Jedi and Sith weren't biologically isolated from other human beings either. Anakin knocked up Padme, after all.

Comment: They're reproductively isolated from _homo sapiens_, the species that lives on Earth. There are no examples of _homo sapiens_ at all in _Star Wars_.

Comment: Ridiculous argument. By that logic, the Rapanui of Easter Island weren't human for 600 years. Wolves in North America aren't wolves because they're "biologically isolated" from wolves in Eurasia. My pet mice are biologically isolated from the other mice I didn't buy at the pet store. I have seen your edit, and it doesn't assist your argument. Maybe, if one argued that the Humans in the *Star Wars* universe were a case of parallel evolution, you could make the case that they are a separate species, but most theories about humans in *Star Wars* involve time travel.

Comment: This may answer the letter of the question, but clearly doesn't remotely answer the spirit of the question. It's obvious that when OP said "homo sapiens" they meant "**humans from The Galaxy Far Far Away**", and not "humans on earth" - assuming they are 2 different species.

Comment: When the OP said _homo sapiens_ he was getting into technical biological definitions that opened him up to a world of hurt. If that's not what he wants, he should edit the question to remove the reference and just use the vaguely defined term "human".

Comment: This really shouldn't be controversial; it's the most widely accepted definition of what a species is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_Species_Concept#Biological_species_concept

Comment: Please do not get rude and attempt to ridicule the questioner simply because you have misunderstood a rather basic biological concept. Your own link disproves your statement, as the term 'species' is defined "on the basis of reproductive compatibility." Simply living in a different galaxy does not make the humans in the *Star Wars* galaxy reproductively incompatible with the humans on Earth.